# button click save in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, button

i have two buttons . view and viewdaywise.

i need to know which button is clicked right now.

how to store that in session / or any other choice???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store the Button as it's non-serializable, however you can store the ID of button:

```
private void LogLastButton(Button button)
{
   Session["LastButtonId"] = button.ID;
}

protected void ButtonView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.LogLastButton((Button)sender);
}

protected void ButtonViewDayWise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.LogLastButton((Button)sender);
}
```

Then to retrieve the button, you can do something along the lines of the following:

```
Button lastButton = Page.Controls.Find(Session["LastButtonId"].ToString());
```

Comment: I would use ViewState instead Session.